# Submit PUT form in vuetify and laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

im tryng to submit a form with a Laravel API in Vuejs. But i have this issue when i need to edit the user data.

Im using this vform method because i want to upload a avatar picture and in this github accound this guys add this function with npm. (https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform/blob/master/example/upload.html).

The problem i have is in the edit part, when i add a new user the function works. But in edit its says

> **TypeError: this.form_edit.submit is not a function**

Here is my code in the edit view.

If anyone dont understand, sorry english is not my first lenguage, so if you want to ask anything, please do it.

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="90rem" scrollable persistent>
      <v-card outlined class="m-auto center">
        <v-card-title  class="headline grey lighten-2" primary-title>
        {{ $t('edita_usuario') }}
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
             <v-card-actions >
                <v-btn color="error"  @click="closeModal">{{ $t('cancel') }}</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="primary"  @click="update">  {{ $t('update') }}</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
      </v-card-title>

        <v-divider class="mx-4" /><br>

        <v-card-text>
          <form @submit.prevent="update" enctype="multipart/form-data">


            <!--autocomplete="off" -->

             <Success :message="$t('usuario_editado')" v-if="successMessage"/>

             <Error :message="errorMessage" v-if="errorAlert"/>

             <v-spacer></v-spacer>

              <v-row no-gutters>
                  <v-col cols="11"></v-col>
                <v-col cols="3">

                <Card title="" :img="profilePicture" width="300" height="300" />

                <v-col cols="10">
                <v-file-input :label="$t('foto_perfil')" clearable filled prepend-icon="mdi-camera" ref="linkfoto" name="linkfoto" v-on:change="ImageChange"></v-file-input>
                </v-col>
                </v-col>

                <v-col cols="9">
                   <v-row>
                      <v-col cols="5">
                        <v-text-field v-model="form_edit.nombres" :label="$t('name')" name="nombres" />
                      </v-col>

                      <!-- Apellido -->
                      <v-col cols="5">
                        <v-text-field v-model="form_edit.apellidos" :label="$t('last_name')" name="apellidos"/>
                      </v-col>
                   </v-row>

                    <v-row>
                      <v-col cols="10">
                        <v-text-field v-model="form_edit.email" :label="$t('email')" name="email"/>
                      </v-col>
                    </v-row>



                    <v-row>
                      <v-col cols="5">
                         <v-select

         <v-spacer></v-spacer><br>

        <label class="title">Datos de usuario</label>

        <v-row class="justify-center">
             <v-col cols="2"></v-col>
             <v-col cols="4">
              <v-text-field v-model="form_edit.alias" :label="$t('usuario')"  name="alias" autocomplete="new-user"/>
             </v-col>

             <v-col cols="4">
              <v-text-field v-model="form_edit.password" :label="$t('password')" :append-icon="show ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'" :type="show ? 'text' : 'password'" name="password" @click:append="show = !show" disabled autocomplete="newpassword" />
             </v-col>
          </v-row>

                 <!-- Perfil -->
             <v-row class="justify-center">
              <v-col cols="2"></v-col>
                <v-col cols="4">
                 <v-select :items="perfiles" item-text="nombreperfil" item-value="idperfil" :label="$t('tipo_usuario')" v-model="form_edit.idperfil" name="idperfil" required />
              </v-col>

              <v-col cols="4">
                <v-textarea name="input-7-1"
                  filled :label="$t('email_firma')" auto-grow v-model="form_edit.saludo"></v-textarea>
             </v-col>

          </v-row>
             <v-divider/><br>



          </form>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
<script>

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import Form from 'vform'
import objectToFormData from 'object-to-formdata'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  middleware: 'admin',
  name: 'FormEditUser',

  props:['dialog','id'],


  data: () => ({
     form_edit: new Form({
      alias: '',
      password: '',
      nombres:'',
      apellidos:'',
      email:'',
      idperfil:'',
      saludo:'',
      linkfoto:'',
    }),

    profilePicture:'',
    paises:[],
    perfiles:[],

    show: false,
    successMessage : false,
    errorAlert : false,
    errorMessage:'',

  }),

  metaInfo () {
    return { title: 'SIIGDE - ' + this.$t('admin') }
  },


mounted: function(){
    this.loadUsuario();
    this.getPerfiles();
  },


methods: {

 update:function() {

  this.form_edit.submit('put', '/api/usuarios'+this.id, {
        transformRequest: [function (data, headers) { // Transforma el vform a formdata para la imagen. Si no anda tirar npm install
          return objectToFormData(data)
        }],
      })

  //axios.put('/api/usuarios/'+this.id, this.form_edit)
      .then(response => {
        this.successMessage = true;
        this.errorAlert = false;
      })
      .catch(error =>{
        this.errorMessage = error.response.data.errors
        this.successMessage = false;
        this.errorAlert = true
;      })
    },

     getPerfiles : function(){
      axios.get('/api/perfiles/0')
      .then(function(response){
        this.perfiles = response.data;
      }.bind(this));  
    },

  // metodos de la imagen para que cargue o se borre
    ImageChange(e) {
      this.UploadImage(e)
    },

    UploadImage(file){
      let reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (e) =>{
        this.profilePicture = e.target.result; //Asigno al input para que muestre la imagen antes del submit
        this.form_edit.linkfoto = file;
      }
      if(file){
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }else{
        this.profilePicture = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8ab904bf2bea2e8f3c7d76f04df2087c.jpg?s=200&d=mm'
      }
    },

    closeModal: function(){
      let close = false;
      this.errorAlert = false;
      this.successMessage = false;
      this.$emit('closeDialog',close);
    },

    loadUsuario(){
        axios.get('/api/usuarios/'+this.id+'/edit') // Aca traigo los datos del usuario por id que mando en la url
      .then((response) => {
        this.form_edit = response.data;
        if(!this.form_edit.linkfoto){
          this.profilePicture = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8ab904bf2bea2e8f3c7d76f04df2087c.jpg?s=200&d=mm';
        }else{
          this.profilePicture = this.form_edit.linkfoto;
        }

      });
    },
  }, // Cierra el methods
}

</script>
```

Comment: On which event does the error occur, which part of the code?

Comment: @utdev in the update mehod. The first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already saying to run the update function if the use submits your form.
In your update you do not need to submit the form since the event already exists.

Further I am not sure what this line is doing there:

```
<form @submit.prevent="update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Why are you trying to achieve with `...prevent="update"`

I would simply post your form using an xhr request, you could use axios for instance like this:

```
  data() {
    return {
      fields: {},
      errors: {},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.errors = {};
      axios.post('/api/usuarios'+this.id, this.fields).then(response => {
        alert('Message sent!');
        // your logic ...
      }).catch(error => {
        if (error.response.status === 422) {
          this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
        }
      });
    },
```

Comment: @fdmartinez remove that, read through this in the vue docs https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers you could for example say `<form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit"></form>` which would prevent the page from reloading.

Comment: I dont know, i just follow the guide the guy post in github because i need to upload the file,  i already done what you justs say, all data arrives at the back minus the file. Im using vform and the only way to "change" vform to FormData is with the objectToFormData(). In the create method in other view this works fine but i dont know why in this dont.

Comment: You actually don't need a form at all simply add a button with a click event to the update method, there you add the data you want to post to the second argument. You need to go through more tutorials I think, have a look at this: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/vue-axios-post-request-exampleexample.html

Comment: i already do that. Thanks for the guide btw, i can post the form with no problem, the only thing that cannot reach is the file and i dont know why. Always gave me a empty array.